# How to send multiple selected data from modal to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating look up page that able to select multiple values using ajax MVC 5.

User choose subsidiaryClientID before click the look up button, then it will show list of firm's matters in modal form based on subsidiaryClientID. After selected 1 or more firm's matters, click Save to send the selected firm's matters to controller. I'm using jquery ajax to send the selected firm's matters to controller

The problem is I don't know how the selected data should be sent using this technique.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: ???
});
```

I've tried to send data using `$('form').serialize()` but it doesn't work. How to solve this problem?

View:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="lookup-timekeeper-container">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="javascript:getMultipleFirmMatter()" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Client's Matter</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubsidiaryClientID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SubsidiaryClientID, new SelectList(Model.SubsidiaryClients, "SubsidiaryClientID", "Name"), "-- Please Select --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubsidiaryClientID)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirmMatters, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnLookupFirmMatter" data-id="@Model.SubsidiaryClientID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Lookup Firm Matter</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10" id="selectedFirmMatters">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Script:

```
$("#btnLookupFirmMatter").click(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Content("~/FirmMatter/Search?subsidiaryClientID=")' + $("#SubsidiaryClientID").val();
    $.get(url)
        .done(function (data) {
            if (!data.message) {
                $("#lookup-timekeeper-container").html(data);
                $("#myModal").modal(show = true, backdrop = true);
            } else {
                alert(data.message);
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
            }
        });
});

$("#btnSave").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Content("~/FirmMatter/Search/")',
        data: ???
        traditional: true
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        $("#selectedFirmMatters").html(data);
    });

    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Search(int subsidiaryClientID)
{
    var firmMatters = db.FirmMatters.Where(fm => fm.SubsidiaryClientID == subsidiaryClientID);
    List<AssignedFirmMatterData> assignedFirmMattersData = new List<AssignedFirmMatterData>();
    foreach (FirmMatter firmMatter in firmMatters.ToList())
    {
        assignedFirmMattersData.Add(new AssignedFirmMatterData{
            FirmMatterID = firmMatter.FirmMatterID,
            FirmMatterNo = firmMatter.FirmMatterNo,
            Description = firmMatter.Description,
            Assigned = false
        });
    }
    return PartialView("_LookupMultiple", assignedFirmMattersData);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(List<AssignedFirmMatterData> assignedFirmMattersData)
{
    // assignedFirmMattersData is null, how to get the user selected data?
}
```

Partial View:

```
@model List<Application.ViewModels.AssignedFirmMatterData>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.FirmMatterID)
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.Assigned)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirmMatterNo)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change html form to have form id:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "YouController", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "form1" }))


And Send with ajax:

var myData = $('#form1').serializeArray(); 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    datatype: 'JSON',
    data:  { assignedFirmMattersData:  JSON.stringify(myData)},
});
```